# Is arbitrary union of closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Is an arbitrary union of non-trivial closed balls in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ Lebesgue measurable? If so, is it a Borel set?

@George

I still have two questions concerning your sketch of proof.

First, how can you guarantee each of the open balls in the countable union has radius greater than or equal to 1?

Second, I don't know how to use convexity to prove $\mu (B') \leq (1+\epsilon)^{N}\mu(B)$

Comment: Is a point a closed ball?

Comment: A point is a closed ball. Is every set measurable?

Comment: We are considering non-trival closed balls. So a single point is not a closed ball.

Comment: non-Borel measurability is easy enough, for N=2. Consider the union of unit balls centered at Sx{0} for a non-measurable subset S of the reals, and look at its intersection with Rx{1}. Lebesgue measurability looks a bit more interesting.

Comment: @George - that set isn't a union of closed balls in R^2, though...

Comment: David - I think you misunderstood me. If B is the closed unit ball, $\cup\{B+(s,0):s\in S\}$ is a union of closed balls, and is not Borel measurable.

Comment: ...and it is not Lebesgue measurable since its intersection with a Lebesgue measurable set is not measurable.

Comment: George, post your answer as an answer, so we can vote it up. You have answered the second part of the question. Also, it seems that your idea generalizes to all larger $n$ as well.

Comment: @George: If S is a nonmeasurable subset of R, then Sx{0} is a nullset in R^2 and therefore Lebesgue (though not Borel) measurable.

Comment: @Faisal: indeed. I meant to say "Borel measurable" in that last comment.

Comment: @George&Joel: by definition, any subset of a measure zero set such as $R\times 1$ is Lebesgue measurable, so we don't have a counter-example here. I agree with the Borel counter-example though.

Comment: Yes, I was only talking about the counterexample as a counterexample to the Borel statement.

Comment: @George, ah, I see. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @CKD re your edit: did you originally mean that all the balls have the same radius, or varying radii?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, in dimension $N>1$, it does not have to be Borel measurable. E.g., in 2 dimensions, consider, a non Borel measurable subset of the reals $S$, and let $A$ be the union of closed unit balls centered at points $(x,0)$ for all $x\in S$. The intersection of $A$ with $\mathbb{R}\times \{1\}$ is the non-Borel set $S \times \{1\}$, so $A$ is not Borel.

On the other hand, for $N=1$, any union of non-trivial closed intervals is Borel-measurable. If $A$ is such a union and $B$ is the union of the open interiors, then it can be seen that $A$ is just the union of $B$ with (at most countably many) endpoints of connected components of $B$.

---

Lebesgue measurability *does* hold, however. Faisal posted a link for this as I was typing my answer, but I think its still worth giving a brief sketch of the proof I was starting to type (Edit: added more detail, as requested).

1. Reduce the problem to that of balls with at least some positive radius $r$ and within some bounded region. To do this, suppose that $S$ is the set of closed balls and $S_r$ denotes the balls of radius at least $r$ and with center no further than $r$ from the origin. Then,
   $$
   \cup S=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(\cup S_{1/n}\right).
   $$
   As the measurable sets are closed under countable unions, it is enough to show that $\cup S_r$ is Lebesgue measurable for each $r>0$. So, we can assume that all balls are of radius at least $r$ and are within some bounded distance of the origin.
2. Let $A$ be the union of the closed balls, and $B\subseteq A$ be the union of their interiors. This is open so, by second countability, is a union of countably many open balls of radius at least $r$. Also, $A$ lies between $B$ and its closure $\bar B$.
3. Show that the boundary $\bar B\setminus B$ of $B$ has zero measure. If we scale up the radius of each of the countable sequence of open balls used to obtain $B$ by a factor $1+\epsilon$ to get the new set $B^\prime$ then $\mu(B^\prime)\le(1+\epsilon)^N\mu(B)$. Showing this is the tricky part, but it does follow from convexity of the balls: If the balls have radius $r_k$ and centres $x_k$, then consider the sets
   $$
   B_t=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B(r_k,tx_k)
   $$
   for real $t$, so that $B_1=B$. The function $t\mapsto\mu(B_t)$ is increasing in $t\ge0$<sup>*</sup>. Also, $B^\prime= (1+\epsilon)B_{1/(1+\epsilon)}$ giving,
   $$
   \mu(B^\prime)=(1+\epsilon)^{N}\mu(B_{1/(1+\epsilon)})\le(1+\epsilon)^{N}\mu(B)
   $$
   as claimed. As $\bar B\subseteq B^\prime$ we get $\mu(\bar B\setminus B)\le((1+\epsilon)^N-1)\mu(B)$ which can be made as small as we like by choosing ε small.

<sup>*</sup> Edit: in my initial response, I was thinking that [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27032/pushing-convex-bodies-together) is enough to prove that $\mu(B_t)$ is increasing in $t$. However, as Mizar points out in the comments below, this is not clear. Actually, I don't think we can reduce it to that case. However, the result is still true, by the [Kneser-Poulson conjecture](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/kneser_poulsen_conjecture). This states that if the centres of  set of unit balls in Euclidean space are all moved apart, then the measure of their union increases. Although only a conjecture, it has been proved for continuous motions, which applies in our case. Also, expressing each ball of radius greater than some arbitrarily small $r > 0$ as a union of balls of radius $r$, then it still applies in our case for balls of non equal radii.

---

Edit: having seen Faisal's explanation, the proof I outline here is completely different to his. The result Faisal quotes is a bit more general as it applies to convex sets with nonempty interior, rather than just balls. However, the proof given above also works for symmetric convex sets with nonempty interiors. As every convex set with nonempty interior is a union of (translates of) symmetric ones, this implies the same result

Comment: Can your argument handle an arbitrary union of circles?

Comment: Circles? You mean closed 2-balls? It will handle arbitrary unions of convex sets with nonempty interior, which is precisely the result Faisal just quoted.

Comment: Actually, were you asking about my argument above or below the line?

Comment: I meant the boundary. In two dimensions, circles (without the interior).

Comment: If S is a non-Lebesgue measurable subset of the positive reals, then the union set of circles centered at the origin with radius in S is not Lebesgue measurable. Neither is the union of unit circles centered at (x,0) for x in S (look at its intersection with Rx{y} for |y| < 1).

Comment: George, I still have two questions concerning your sketch of proof.

First, how can you guanrantee each of the open balls in the countable union has radius greater than or equal to 1?

Second, I don't know how to use convexity to prove $\mu (B') \leq (1+\epsilon)^{N}\mu(B)$

Comment: @CKD: Added more detail.

Comment: Actually, differentiating that inequality wrt $\epsilon$ shows that the surface area of a union of unit balls is bounded by N times its volume. (Just seemed like an interesting point).

Comment: @George: Thanks for your patience. My first question is that, in Step 2, you write B as a union of countably many open balls of radius at least r, but how can we control the radius of the balls in the countable union (to make it $\geq r$)?

My second question is answered by the details you added. Thanks! 

Comment: Intuitively the idea is that, as t increases, the distance between the balls increases, so the overlap decreases. The measure of their union must increase as t increases.

Comment: by step 1, we are only looking at a union of balls of radius at least r

Comment: Maybe the bit you were missing is that in a second countable space, the union of a collection of open sets equals the union of some countable subcollection.

Comment: Why is $t\to \mu(B_t)$ unimodal? I see this reduces immediately to a finite number of balls, but how do you reduce it to the case of two balls? (Sorry for necroposting)

Comment: @Mizar: I fixed the answer (better late than never, I suppose), although it does make the answer rather more complicated.

Comment: I think your argument must be revised at the last step. That is, the closure need not be contained in $B'$. For example, consider an open cover of $\mathbb Q\cap (0,1)$ with total measure $0.5$. The closure is $[0,1]$.

Comment: In your step 1, it appears that every ball contains the origin?

Comment: The fact that $\overline{B}\setminus B$ has zero Lebesgue measure when the radii are bounded below should follow from an old argument of Erdos that every point in the set has Lebesgue density at most $1/2$ (originally given for the levelsets of the distance function). With some more care it could be shown that it's actually $(n-1)$-rectifiable (covered by countably many $(n-1)$-dimensional Lipschitz graphs) since it has a one-sided cone property. A more recent result implies that the graphs can be taken of class $C^2$, since the set has a one-sided ball property, see arxiv.org/abs/1703.09561.

Answer (score 19):

A google search reveals that an arbitrary union of (nondegenerate) convex sets is Lebesgue measurable: see

[Balcerzak and Kharazishvili. *On uncountable unions and intersections of measurable sets*.
Georgian Math. J. **6** (1999), no. 3, 201–212.](http://www.emis.de/journals/GMJ/vol6/v6n3-1.pdf)

**Edit**: As requested, here's a summary of the proof.

The authors prove that an arbitrary union of (closed, nondegenerate) $n$-simplices $\{ S_t \}_{t \in T}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measurable. First a preliminary definition:

> A bounded set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be **$\alpha$-regular**, for $\alpha$ a positive real number, if $\lambda(X) \geq \alpha \lambda(V(X))$, where $V(X)$ is a closed ball with minimal diameter for which the inclusion $X \subset V(X)$ holds.

Observe that an $n$-simplex is $\alpha$-regular for some $\alpha \in (0,1]$. Thus

$$ \bigcup_{t \in T} S_t = \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \  \bigcup \{ S_t \colon S_t \text{ is } \textstyle{\frac{1}{m}}\text{-regular} \}. $$

So in order to show that $\cup_t S_t$ is Lebesgue measurable, it suffices to show that $X_m = \cup \{ S_t \colon S_t \text{ is } \frac{1}{m}\text{-regular} \}$ is Lebesgue measurable for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Towards this end, given $x \in S_t$ and $c \in (0,1)$, let $S_t(x,c)$ denote the image of $S_t$ under the map $y \mapsto x + c(y-x)$. Then

$$ \mathcal{F}_m = \{ S_t(x,c) \colon S_t \text{ is } \textstyle{\frac{1}{m}}\text{-regular}, x \in S_t, c \in (0,1) \} $$

is a Vitali covering of $X_m$. The Vitali covering theorem now takes us home: the countable subcollection $\mathcal{F}_m^\ast \subset \mathcal{F}_m$ produced by the theorem has a Lebesgue measurable union $\cup \mathcal{F}_m^\ast$, which also satisfies

$$ \bigcup \mathcal{F}_m^\ast \subset X_m \quad\text{and}\quad \lambda(X_m \backslash \bigcup \mathcal{F}_m^\ast) = 0. $$

Comment: It would be kind of you to summarize the argument.

Comment: Actually, convexity is hardly required here. I think it is enough that, for each t, there is a positive c such that $\mu(S_t\cap B_r(x))\ge cr^N$ for all $x\in S_t$ and $r > 0$. The construction given for the Vitali cover shows this is true for convex sets of nonempty interior (and it is clear for balls).

Answer (score -6):

EDIT: While I say separability may be important in the answer below, I think having
a countable basis (second-countable?) is even more important for the answer. END EDIT.

Since R^n is separable ( has a countable dense subset ), the arbitrary union may be replaceable by a countable union.  If so, then then set is Borel.  I assume that each closed ball has nontrivial radius and can be approximated by a union from a countable collection of closed balls ( or their complements by a countable union of open balls ).

Note that separability is key here, as is the nontriviality of every closed ball in the collection.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman. 2010.10.26

Comment: You can't replace by a countable union - for example see my comment to the question.

Comment: You can't approximate an arbitrary closed ball with a union from a countable collection of closed balls.  For instance, suppose you were tempted to take as your collection $\mathcal{C}$ the closed balls of rational radius centered at a point with rational coordinates.  Let $B$ be an arbitrary closed ball.  You would need $B = \bigcup _{B' \in \mathcal{C}, B' \subset B} B'$.  It's easy to see that for $x$ in the boundary of $B$, $x$ lies in that union iff $x$ has rational coordinates, but of course most of the points on the boundary won't.